# Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain"

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, dockerfile, mime-types

It's the whole day I'm stuck with this error. I did an angular app, if I run it from visual studio code terminal it works fine. Then I Dockerized this app, I remember firstly it was working, then I have no clue why it is not working anymore. Tried from 2 different PCs, same problem. This is the error I get in console:
[image]
These three files get generated inside the dist folder, in the index.html:
[image]
I have no clue where they come from in all honestly, this is my index file (in source):
[image]
This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/front-end-blog-demo /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And this is my nginx.conf file:

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
    }
}
```

Reading on internet, looks like it's some problem due the subfolder, but I literally tried everything and nothing is working.
This is inside the angular.json, the output path:
[image]

Any idea how to solve that? If not, do you mind send me your Dockerfile code for an angular app? Maybe that Dockerfile is wrong? Or pass me the nginx file too? I don't know anymore what to do to solve that.